# How to get active Google profile name when I get the active Url from google chrome browser using C#

Tags: java, c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

iam using this code to get the currently active tab open URL from Google Chrome browser.

```
 public static string GetActiveTabUrl()
    {
        Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");

        if (procsChrome.Length <= 0)
            return null;

        foreach (Process proc in procsChrome)
        {
            // the chrome process must have a window 
            if (proc.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                continue;

            // to find the tabs we first need to locate something reliable - the 'New Tab' button 
            AutomationElement root = AutomationElement.FromHandle(proc.MainWindowHandle);
            var SearchBar = root.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address and search bar"));
            if (SearchBar != null)
                return (string)SearchBar.GetCurrentPropertyValue(ValuePatternIdentifiers.ValueProperty);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

is there any way that I can return the current Profile name too? the profile name which I mean is found on the upper right part of the google chrome browser so it maybe has more than a profile with different names I want only to get the current name with the URL it comes from this function. I can open or use many profiles at the same time in google chrome, so I want to get the active Tab URL and the profile name with it or the email of that profile.
this an image of the profile name i want it from chrome to be sent with the currently active tab URL.
[image: profile name]

so i expect something like that for example to be done in c# to get the profile name 
`var SearchBar = root.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "profile email"));`

last thing it can be c# or java codes if it can be better do in it also any solution that can get it in any programming language, please help with any information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to dive into the HTML a little bit. Use chrome's developer features and inspect the HTML. You will find what class the username is under and the text is stored as the title find an example below.

```
<a class="gb_b gb_ib gb_R" href="https://accounts.google.com/" role="button" tabindex="0" title="Google Account: FillerFirstName FillerLastName (fillerEmail@gmail.com)" aria-expanded="false"><span class="gb_db gbii"></span></a>
```

You can accomplish this in many different ways with C#. I would recommend Selenium.

Comment: i tried to make some search on it but nothing so, can you add to the answer any code even using Selenium library on how to get the profile name too?

Comment: Here is a link that will help you understand it. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1053815/Grab-and-parse-data-using-Selenium-WebDriver-Part

Comment: You will want to use the findElement keyword. This will allow you to find the username within the html I showed in my answer above. Once you have found the object you can then display the title tag, which contains the username.